# how do I get the text content of the clicked element?

Tags: php, jquery

code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".special").click(function(){
          courses = this.id;
          location.href = "courses-college.php?courses="+courses;
        });
    });
</script>

<ul>
    <li class="special" id="design">Design</li>
    <li class="special" id="forestry">Forestry</li>
    <li class="special" id="vetenerary">Vetenerary</li>
    <li class="special" id="diploma(engg)">Diploma(Engg)</li>
    <li class="special" id="BTechMTech">Dual Degree(Engg)</li>
    <li class="special" id="BBAMBA">Dual Degree(Mgmt)</li>
</ul>
```

In this code when I click it get Id one by one that's ok but I want that if I click and get id='BTechMtech' then it will append "&" with link i.e.

```
courses-college.php?courses=BtechMtech&Dual Degree(Engg)
```

Similarly for Dual Degree(Mgmt). So, How can I fix this problem ?please help.

Thank You

Comment: You can't just be asking how do I get the text content of the clicked element, because that should be easy enough to research, right?

Comment: If he took the time to post a question, then it must be of help to him. Quickly pinpointing the needed place in the API takes some amount of experience, which the question author may not necessarily have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".special").click(function(){
          courses = this.id;
          title = $(this).text();
          location.href = "courses-college.php?courses="+courses+"&title="+encodeURIComponent(title);
        });
    });
</script>

<ul>
    <li class="special" id="design">Design</li>
    <li class="special" id="forestry">Forestry</li>
    <li class="special" id="vetenerary">Vetenerary</li>
    <li class="special" id="diploma(engg)">Diploma(Engg)</li>
    <li class="special" id="BTechMTech">Dual Degree(Engg)</li>
    <li class="special" id="BBAMBA">Dual Degree(Mgmt)</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jzccb8dg/

Answer (score 1):

Making use of **encodeURIComponent** helps you having the meta characters to be escaped.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".special").click(function(){
      title = $(this).text();
      location.href = "courses-college.php?courses="+encodeURIComponent(title);
    });
});
</script>
```